# How to implement jumping on the left and right?

Tags: c++, game-loop, sdl, sdl2

I am trying to make a platform game in C++ and SDL2.

I tried to add a jump in the update() function of the main code below , but it does not work as expected, as you can see in the video:

Note: I did not set any fixed position after the jump so the player will keep falling when jumping unless I press Left/Right/Up/Down keys to stop it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=765KsXgqJG8&feature=youtu.be

1. Jumping is not responsive all times: sometimes the player just walks instead of jumping and I have no idea why
2. It jumps to an inconsistent height each time, depending on when I press the left/right keys
3. The left/right keys should not work after they have been pressed once (when it comes to jumping) but they work, allowing the player to turn and steer themselves in mid-air, and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
//test
if(Player.State == PLAYER_JUMPING && keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
   Player.XPosition -= 2.5f; //jump on the left
                                              
if(Player.State == PLAYER_JUMPING && keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT])
   Player.XPosition += 2.5f; //jump on the right    
  

//Actual code that works to jump up
    
enum EPlayerState 
    {
        PLAYER_STILL = 0, //0
        PLAYER_MOVING_LEFT,
        PLAYER_MOVING_RIGHT,
        PLAYER_MOVING_UP,
        PLAYER_MOVING_DOWN,
        PLAYER_JUMPING,
        NUM_PLAYER_STATES //6
        
    };
                
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                
struct SPlayer
    {
        .......
        float           XPosition   = 0.f;
        float           YPosition    = 408.0f;
        float           Velocity    =  160.0f;
        float           JumpVelocity = -200.0f;
        float           Gravity = 250.0f;
        EPlayerState    State       = PLAYER_STILL;  
        .....
    };
 //////////////////////////////////////////   

SPlayer  Player;
////////////////////////////////////////




//POLLING EVENTS
              
             // The user is holding down a key on the keyboard
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            {
                switch(Event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                      
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    {
                        isLeftPressed = true;
                        Player.State = PLAYER_MOVING_LEFT;
                  
                        break;
                    }
      
                        
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                   {
                        isRightPressed = true;
                        Player.State = PLAYER_MOVING_RIGHT;
                   
                        break;
                    }
    
                        
                    case SDLK_UP:
                    {   isUpPressed = true;
                        Player.State = PLAYER_MOVING_UP;

                        break;
                    }
                        
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                    {   isDownPressed = true;
                        Player.State = PLAYER_MOVING_DOWN;
                        
                        break;
                    }
                        
                        
                    case SDLK_s:
                    {   isSPressed = true;
                        Player.State = PLAYER_JUMPING;
                        
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            
                break;
            }
                
                // The user is releasing a key on the keyboard
            case SDL_KEYUP:
            {
                switch(Event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    {
                        isLeftPressed = false;
                        if(Player.State == PLAYER_MOVING_LEFT)
                        Player.State = PLAYER_STILL;
                        
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    {
                        isRightPressed = false;
                        if(Player.State == PLAYER_MOVING_RIGHT)
                        Player.State = PLAYER_STILL;
                    
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    case SDLK_UP:
                    {
                        isUpPressed = false;
                        if(Player.State == PLAYER_MOVING_UP)
                            Player.State = PLAYER_STILL; 
                        
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                    {
                        isDownPressed = false;
                        if(Player.State == PLAYER_MOVING_DOWN)
                            Player.State = PLAYER_STILL; 
                        
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    case SDLK_s:
                    {
          //nothing here so we keep jumping pressing S once    
                        break;
                    }
                    
                        
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
                
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // in Update() function I have:  
    //Jumping UP  

if(Player.State == PLAYER_JUMPING)
{
    Player.YPosition += Player.JumpVelocity * (float)DeltaTime; //Yposition + (-200.0f * Deltatime)
    Player.JumpVelocity += Player.Gravity * (float)DeltaTime; //-200.0f + 250.0f * DeltaTime       
}
else //reset JumpVelocity to original value

{
    Player.JumpVelocity = -200.0f;
}
```

Comment: Please do not delete and re-post the same question. For our automated systems, this can look like an attempt to bypass moderation, and result in automated restrictions being applied to your account.

Comment: Ok, thought was better to start anew after all the edits. Noted, thanks for your help